# Generation of .tlb Files in Windows 7 Pro 32-bit

Tags: c#, c++, dll, typelib

I have a C++ DLL that imports a .tlb file generated in a C# project. The C++ DLL is a wrapper DLL containing functions that call the corresponding C# functions.

When I call the C++ functions on the computer that I built the projects, all works well. But when I copy the DLL's and generated tlb's to another computer with the same exact version of Windows and installed programs andI call the C++ functions, it breaks with a COM error. However, after recompiling the projects on the new computer, everything works again.

I already checked the "Work on All Computers" for both projects but this keeps happening.  What else do I need to do for the DLL's to work on all computers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HRESULT you get would be crucial to diagnose this.  Forced to guess: did you run Regasm.exe on that machine?  Required to make the necessary registry entries so COM can find the server.  It is automatic when you build in the IDE.

Comment: I'll try to do this one more time. I'll inform of this tomorrow. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Regarding HRESULT I don't know how to see that cause I first use a python project to call the c++ functions. How can I make it to see the HRESULT?

Comment: You'll have to use a C++ debugger if you don't get a decent diagnostic.  If my guess is right then it won't fail tomorrow.

Comment: how can I call the c++ debugger when I'm using the python app? Should I ask this question here? :P

Comment: I would attach the debugger.  Maybe there are better techniques for Python, I recommend you ask it as a separate question, using the "Python" tag.  I imagine you'll need to explain how you call C++ code from a Python program.