# Working with .tlb files

Tags: c#, com, dll

I've created a c# com interop dll project that generates both .dll and .tlb files.
When I use them on the computer that I built everythig, all works fine.
But when I pass it to another computer (with the same windows installed), it doesn't work.

I allready made the:
Regasm.exe SoundLogDLL.dll /tlb:SoundLogDLL.tlb

command, but still doesn't work.
I also done the work in all computers in vs2008 before releasing it!

Is there anything else that I have to do?

Comment: Did you run Regasm, on the target machine?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more details (are you getting some exception) than *still doesn't work*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generation of .tlb Files in Windows 7 Pro 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927914/generation-of-tlb-files-in-windows-7-pro-32-bit)

Comment: What error were you actually getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two weeks and lot of time spent, I've discovered what was missing:

Regasm.exe SoundLogDLL.dll /codebase

and all worked :)

Comment: did you use that command instead of "Regasm.exe SoundLogDLL.dll /tlb:SoundLogDLL.tlb" or in conjunction with it somehow

Comment: I don't remember but I think it was just this one.